# When I add a subdivision surface modifier it creates spikes at the loopcuts

Tags: modeling, modifiers, smooth

[image: Before I add the subsurf modifier.][image: After I add the subsurf modifier.]

I am making a character model with a cylinder as its base. When I add a subdivision surface modifier it smooths out a lot of it but it makes the body smaller around and creates tiny spikes where I put loopcuts.

Comment: Hello, maybe you have inner faces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have normals that are inverted. Check them by enabling Face Orientation overlay:

[image]
f
You can select faces and hit  <kbd>Alt</kbd>   +   <kbd>N</kbd>   ->   <kbd>F</kbd>  to flip normals.

[image]

You could also select everything and use Recalculate Normals  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>N</kbd> , but that algorithm will chose normal direction randomly when you have some types of geometry like floating planes or anything else it cannot "understand".